# Compare 2 csv files and highlight row on match

Tags: php, csv, match, unique

I have following working code to compare 2 csv files - base.csv file to compare to master.csv file using function row_compare. For now I am echoing the master.csv file followed by echoing the match items. I need help to echo only the master.csv file in a table format and highlight the rows that match the base.csv files items.

```
function row_compare($a, $b)
{
    if ($a === $b) {
        return 0;
    }

    return (implode("",$a) < implode("",$b) ) ? -1 : 1;
}

$file1 = new SplFileObject("master.csv");
$file1->setFlags(SplFileObject::READ_CSV);

$file2 = new SplFileObject("../../base.csv");
$file2->setFlags(SplFileObject::READ_CSV);

foreach ($file1 as $row) {
    $csv_1[] = $row;
}

foreach ($file2 as $row) {
    $csv_2[] = $row;
}

$unique_to_csv1 = array_udiff($csv_1, $csv_2, 'row_compare');
$unique_to_csv2 = array_udiff($csv_2, $csv_1, 'row_compare');

$all_unique_rows = array_merge($unique_to_csv1,$unique_to_csv2);

foreach($all_unique_rows as $unique_row) {
    foreach($unique_row as $element) {
        echo $element . "   ";
    }
    echo '<br />';
}
```

master.csv

```
02Jan2020,Marilyn Salary,-31570.29,162252.14,,
02Jan2020,Nancy Skosana,-30000,132252.14,,
02Jan2020,Johan Consulting Fees,-30000,102252.14,,
02Jan2020,Carol Consulting Fees,-30000,72252.14,,
02Jan2020,Juanic Salary,-24239.22,48012.92,,
02Jan2020,Shirley Salary,-14382.67,33630.25,,
06Jan2020,Carol Consulting Fees,-10000,72252.14,,
06Jan2020,Juanic Salary,-4239.22,48012.92,,
06Jan2020,Shirley Salary,-4382.67,33630.25,,
```

Base.csv

```
ADE Labeling
Johan Consulting Fees
Best Board
Nancy Skosana
Cabstrut
Juanic Salary
Cybertrek
Drizit
Shirley Salary
```

Output Format

[image]

So all rows containing Johan Consulting Fees, Shirley Salary, Juanic Salary and Nancy Skosan should change to yellow

Comment: Can you also show your expected output based on above example values from master.csv and base.csv?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
$file1 = new SplFileObject("master.csv");
$file1->setFlags(SplFileObject::READ_CSV);

$file2 = new SplFileObject("base.csv");
$file2->setFlags(SplFileObject::READ_CSV);

foreach ($file1 as $row) {
    $csv_1[] = $row;
}

//If there are just one column, just make a single level array
foreach ($file2 as $row) {
    $csv_2[] = $row[0];
}

//Create html-table with values from master csv file (master csv array $csv_1)
//and if name is the same in other array , make <tr class="yellow"> which
//would highlight the row
$html = '<table>';
foreach($csv_1 as $inner_arr) {
    $name = $inner_arr[1];    
    $arr_in = in_array($name, $csv_2); 

    $html .= '<tr';
    //Name exists in the other array, hightlight this row
    if ($arr_in !== false) {
        $html .= ' class="yellow"';
    }
    $html .= '>';

    foreach($inner_arr as $inner_value) {   
        $html .= '<td>';       
        $html .= $inner_value;    
        $html .= '</td>';
    }
    $html .= '</tr>';

}
$html .= '</table>';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Table</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    .yellow {background:yellow;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
  <?php echo $html;?>  
</body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE** (on request from OP):
**If you have several "base"-files you could do like this:**
REPLACE first part of code with this:

```
<?php
$file1 = new SplFileObject("master.csv");
$file1->setFlags(SplFileObject::READ_CSV);

$basefiles = array('base.csv', 'base2.csv', 'base3.csv');
$file2 = array();
foreach($basefiles as $key=>$bf) {
    $file2[$key] = new SplFileObject( $bf );
    $file2[$key]->setFlags(SplFileObject::READ_CSV);
}

foreach ($file1 as $row) {
    $csv_1[] = $row;
}

$csv_2 = array();
//Go through all fileobjects and create arr ($csv_2) based on those files
foreach ($file2 as $file_object) {        
    //If there are just one column
    foreach($file_object as $row) {
        $csv_2[] = $row[0];
    }
}

//And then continue with creation with html-string as above
//(where line comment starts with:
//Create html-table with values from master csv file)
```

**UPDATE2:**
A better approach would be (from @Nigels recommendation) to skip the creation of file objects into a separate array and create the file array in the first loop where the file objects are created for each file.

```
<?php
$file1 = new SplFileObject("master.csv");
$file1->setFlags(SplFileObject::READ_CSV);

foreach ($file1 as $row) {
    $csv_1[] = $row;
}

$basefiles = array('base.csv', 'base2.csv', 'base3.csv');
$csv_2 = array();
foreach($basefiles as $key=>$bf) {
    $file2 = new SplFileObject( $bf );
    $file2->setFlags(SplFileObject::READ_CSV);
    foreach($file2 as $row) {
        $csv_2[] = $row[0];
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not able to answer you yet as whole, but I would create a file array (instead of using $file2) and check agains that array. I will get back to you as soon as I can.

Comment: Updated now as you asked for.

Comment: Would it make more sense to read the data instead of creating a list of the files and the iterate over this list to read the data.

Comment: @JohanVenables - hm did you not accept Nigels answer yesterday?

Comment: @NigelRen - It would make sense depending of the size of the files. Smaller files with arrays does work faster. Larger file arrays take a lot of memory from the server.

Comment: I'm talking about `$file2`, you create a list of the `SplFileObject`'s and then you `foreach ($file2 as $file_object) {` and build a list of all of the rows.  If you did this second operation instead of building `$file2`, you don't need the array of objects just and array of rows.

Comment: As for accepting an answer, doesn't really matter as long as they solve their problem.

Comment: aha you're right about $file2. I could basically have the creation of $csv_2 in the first loop with $basefiles. Good point! :-)

Comment: I didn't know it was possible to unaccept an answer... :-)

Answer (score 1):

This code will just output an * if the name (the second column) in the master file is in the data file (comments in code)...

```
$file2 = new SplFileObject("../../base.csv");
$file2->setFlags(SplFileObject::READ_CSV);

// Read in second file, just create an entry indexed by the name
foreach ($file2 as $row) {
    $csv_2[$row[0]] = 1;
}

$file1 = new SplFileObject("master.csv");
$file1->setFlags(SplFileObject::READ_CSV);

echo "<table>";
// Loop through the master file
foreach($file1 as $row) {
    if ( isset($csv_2[$row[1]]) ) {
        $class = "yellow";
    }
    else    {
        $class = "green";
    }
    echo '<tr class="'.$class.'"><td>';
    echo implode("</td><td>", $row);
    echo '</td></tr>';
}
echo "</table>";
```

For reading multiple data files, this moves the reading to a function...

```
function readDataFiles ( array $fileNames )  {
    $csv = [];

    foreach ( $fileNames as $fileName )    {
        $file2 = new SplFileObject($fileName);
        $file2->setFlags(SplFileObject::READ_CSV);

        foreach ($file2 as $row) {
            $csv[$row[0]] = 1;
        }
    }

    return $csv;
}
$csv_2 = readDataFiles(["base1.csv", "base2.csv"]);
```

Comment: ah. clever to set the name as a key. Are there any drawbacks with that method?

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld, if you just need to know an entry exists then not as far as I know.

Comment: Just one more thing if I have 10 x base files (base1.csv, base2.csv, base3.csv ... etc) how do I loop through them to check against master.csv file

Comment: If they are the same or similar comparisons, it would be easier to just read them all into the same array, so repeat the `foreach ($file2 as $row) {...` loop for each of the files (or create a function to do it for you).

Comment: I tried to read multiple csv files in same array but then gives me only the results of the last csv file match

 `$file2 = new SplFileObject("../../base.csv");

$file2->setFlags(SplFileObject::READ_CSV);

$file2 = new SplFileObject("../../base1.csv");

$file2->setFlags(SplFileObject::READ_CSV); `